# elasticsearch : How can i tell _reindex api in to continue indexing docs while source index still receiving new docs?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

I have daily created indices, these indices are filled by an agent which collects a logs every second of the day, and i'am reindexing them (by field) to new indices using _reindex api.

How can i tell _reindex api to still reindixing while the source index still receiving new documents ?

Any help woould be really appriciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot force reindex API to be online to reindex new received documents.

but I have solution. you can add a date field (index_time) to your source index. write an hourly cron job to run reindex API with a query to get last hour indexed docs via index_time.

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-000001",
     "query": {
        "filter" :{
            "query": {
                "range": {
                   "index_time": {"gte" : "now-1h"}
                          }
                      }
                   } 
               }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-new-index-000001"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Hamid, thank you for the response, in fact i don't know how to call _reindex api with cron job, any idea please ?

Comment: are you using linux based OS?

Comment: In fact i used cronjob object of k8s.

Comment: Let me come back to your answer, actually i'dont have access to fluentd, so i can't edit the source index  ( for adding the field that mentioned), is there other way  that i can reindex in real time?

Comment: is there any timestamp field? logstash put index_time in a timestamp field by default. share a document.

Comment: sorry to respond you late.  Yes i have, what do you thik if i use "while true" loop to reindex all docs betwwen now and 2mn before  for example ? with this manner, can i have performance problems ?